# Tooltip with full screen image

Tags: javascript, image, tooltip, fullscreen, responsive

First of all, sorry, because probably this is kind of a long shot. My coding knowledge is very limited and everything I always do is based on tutorials, and codes I see around.

Basically, I created [this site](http://jelato.love/mag/index.html), with a list of galleries and institutions. When one hovers on the name of the venue there's a tooltip with image that comes out and follows the mouse. I really liked this effect but realized it is not working that well on small screens such like the laptop ones.

Is there any easy way to modify this js so I can have an image coming out as full screen (covering the whole screen) fixed and responsive?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var tooltipSpans = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-span');
      window.onmousemove = function (e) {
      var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY,
        i, l = tooltipSpans.length;
      for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          tooltipSpans[i].style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
          tooltipSpans[i].style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
        }
      };
</script>
```

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image as background image of your body-tag. And set following styling to it:

```
#container {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here the javascript changes:

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  var i, l = tooltipSpans.length;
  for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
    var backgroundimageSRC = tooltipSpans[i].children.getAttribute("src");
    document.getElementById("conatiner").style.backgroundImage = "url("+ backgroundimageSRC +")";
  }
}
```

Maybe you have to change a little bit. But I think it will do the magic.

Comment: I tried this, [online already](http://jelato.love/mag/index.html) but seems like I cannot make it work. Anyway, thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Plus, maybe I should have said it, each venue has a different image.